# dplyr: Maximum across arbitrary number of variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to take the maximum of a number of variables within a pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_foo = data_frame(
  a = rnorm(100),
  b = rnorm(100),
  c = rnorm(100)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    `Max 1` = max(a, b, c, na.rm = TRUE),
    `Max 2` = pmap_dbl(list(a, b, c), max, na.rm = TRUE),
    `Max 3` = pmax(a, b, c, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

The `purrr::pmap_dbl` solution appears to be clunky -- in that it requires specifying the names of the variables as a list. Is there a way to do away with having to use the `list` keyword so that it is potentially usable programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.` to specify the dataset

```
df_foo %>%
     mutate(Max2 = pmap_dbl(.l = ., max, na.rm = TRUE))
```

and suppose, if we are doing on a subset of columns, then

```
nm1 <- c("a", "b")
df_foo %>%
     mutate(Max2 = pmap_dbl(.l = .[nm1], max, na.rm = TRUE))
```